# How do I enable/disable interrupts in the mspgcc using C?

Tags: c, msp430, mspgcc

How can I enable and disable (clear and set `GIE` `SR` bit) in C using the `mspgcc`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/694733

Comment: @user694733: Not a duplicate. The GIE SR bit in the MSP430 is generally not accessed using simple bitwise operator because there is no symbol defined in C that represents the status register.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the status register (SR) is a processor register, not a normal memory mapped register.  I found the solution, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*interrupt.c
ganeshredcobra@gmail.com
GPL
*/
#include <msp430g2553.h>
#define LED1 BIT0
#define LED2 BIT6
#define BUTTON BIT3
volatile unsigned int i;//to prevent optimization
void main(void)
{
WDTCTL=WDTPW+WDTHOLD;
P1DIR |= (LED1+LED2);//
P1OUT &= ~(LED1+LED2);
P1IE |= BUTTON;
P1IFG &= ~BUTTON;

//__enable_interrupt();//enable all interrupts
_BIS_SR(LPM4_bits+GIE);
for(;;)
{}
}

//port1 interrupt service routine
#pragma vector=PORT1_VECTOR
__interrupt void Port_1(void)
{
P1OUT ^= (LED1+LED2);
P1IFG &= ~BUTTON;
P1IES ^= BUTTON;
}
```

This is an example of interrupt
http://importgeek.wordpress.com/tag/msp430-launchpad/

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the __eint() / __dint() intrinsics:

```
#include <intrinsics.h>
...
    __eint();
    /* Interrupts enabled */
    __dint();
    /* Interrupts disabled */
```

Or you can use the __bis_status_register() / __bic_status_register() intrinsics:

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <intrinsics.h>
...
    __bis_status_register(GIE);
    /* Interrupts enabled */
    __bic_status_register(GIE);
    /* Interrupts disabled */
```

Or one of the many other compatibility definitions in intrinsics.h. Note that there are also some special versions such as __bis_status_register_on_exit() / __bic_status_register_on_exit() which will change the state of the flag on exit from an ISR.

Comment: I'm using the `mspgcc` and I get `fatal error: intrinsics.h: No such file or directory`, also the `__eint()` and `__dint()` produce errors.

Comment: @tylerjw: What version of mspgcc are you using? You should probably add that information to the question as it would change the validity of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Through experimentation I found it can be enabled with `_BIS_SR(GIE);` and disabled with `_BIC_SR(GIE);` without including anything but the standard `msp430g2553.h` file.